# Name of the head of each department

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having the data in employee table like in the below.

```
EId FName LName  Sal  Manager Department
1   sham    rao 5000    2   sales
2   Raju    rao 6000    4   Insurance
3   Shila   rao 4000    4   Insurance
5   test    rao 500     7   Sports
6   sham    rao 5000    2   sales
7   Jane    rao 5000    0   Head
4   Rajesh  rao 600     7   Sports
```

And i have to find the name of the head of the department like in the below.

```
ManagerName            Manager      department
Rajurao                2            sales
Rajeshrao              4            Insurance
Janerao                7            Sports
Null                  Null          Head
```

and i've tried the below query to find it out but no luck

```
select concat (first_name,'',last_name) as name,department from employee 
where   exists (select distinct manager from employee where  exists (select department, 
count(manager) from employee group by department))
```

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: How does Raju Rao's manager change from 2 to 4 in the final data?

Comment: Hint: self-join `on EId = coalesce(manager,0)`

Comment: "no luck" and "doesn't work" are not helpful comments. In addition, it seems your own desired output is incorrect. Raju rao is in Insurance department, so how can that person be manager of sales? And of the 2 employees in Insurance, what logic determines which is manager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ManName.FName + ManName.LName AS ManagerName, CASE WHEN Dep.Manager = 0 THEN Null ELSE Dep.Manager END AS Manager, Dep.Department
FROM Employee Dep
LEFT JOIN Employee ManName ON Dep.Manager = ManName.EId
```

Answer (score 1):

Joining the same table to itself will do the trick:

```
SELECT CONCAT(first_name,'',last_name) AS emplself.Name, emplself.Department 
FROM employee AS empl
INNER JOIN employee AS emplself ON empl.EId=emplself.Manager
```

Comment: nope, already i've tried this one but it won't give the accurate output

Answer (score 0):

Try This below code using Recursive Cte

```
;WITH DataCTE (EId, FName, LName,  Sal , Manager, Department)
AS
(
SELECT 1,'sham'    ,'rao', 5000 , 2 ,'sales'
UNION ALL SELECT 2,'Raju'    ,'rao', 6000 , 4 ,'Insurance'
UNION ALL SELECT 3,'Shila'   ,'rao', 4000 , 4 ,'Insurance'
UNION ALL SELECT 5,'Test'    ,'rao', 500  , 7 ,'Sports'
UNION ALL SELECT 6,'sham'    ,'rao', 5000 , 2 ,'sales'
UNION ALL SELECT 7,'Jane'    ,'rao', 5000 , 0 ,'Head'
UNION ALL SELECT 4,'Rajesh'  ,'rao', 600  , 7 ,'Sports'
)
,CTE_Hierarchy
AS

(
SELECT EId, 
       CONCAT(FName,' ',LName) AS EmpName ,
       Manager AS ManagerId,
       Department
 FROM  DataCTE
 WHERE Manager = 0
 UNION ALL

 SELECT e.EId, 
        CONCAT(e.FName,' ',e.LName) ,
        e.Manager,
        e.Department
 FROM CTE_Hierarchy c
 INNER JOIN DataCTE e
 ON c.EId = e.Manager

 )
 SELECT  DISTINCT EmpName, 
 ManagerId,
        ISNULL((SELECT  CONCAT(d.FName,' ',d.LName)
         FROM DataCTE d
         WHERE d.EId = CTE_Hierarchy.ManagerId),'')  AS ManagerName,
 Department
 FROM CTE_Hierarchy
 ORDER BY 2
```

Result

```
EmpName     ManagerId   ManagerName     Department
----------------------------------------------------
Jane rao        0                        Head
sham rao        2         Raju rao       sales
Raju rao        4         Rajesh rao     Insurance
Shila rao       4         Rajesh rao     Insurance
Rajesh rao      7         Jane rao       Sports
Test rao        7         Jane rao       Sports
```